# Disconnect Reflux listenTo method

Tags: reactjs, refluxjs

So, I have two stores. First pageStore serves business logic of specific page, and second globalStore logic of Android/iOS global events. 
When user enters specific page React.componentDidMount calls

```
pageEntered: function () {
    this.listenTo(globalStore, this.locationUpdated);
},
```

so from this my pageStore started to listen global storage for GPS updates. But is there any way to disconnect listenTo on React.componentWillUnmount ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an example how to unsubscribe from a store listening (taken from the official examples):

```
var Status = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() { },
    onStatusChange: function(status) {
        this.setState({
            currentStatus: status
        });
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.unsubscribe = statusStore.listen(this.onStatusChange);
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        this.unsubscribe();
    },
    render: function() {
        // render specifics
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to think about what's happening in the example above:

```
var myFunc = function(){
    console.log("This gets fired immediately");
    var randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random()*10);
    return function() {
        return randomNumber;
    }
}

var a = myFunc(); //Console log fires IMMEDIATELY, a is the returned function

a(); //some integer from 1 to 10
```

Since myFunc is invoked when we assign it to a variable, the console.log fires immediately-- it is like this.unsubscribe = statusStore.listen(this.onStatusChange); which "turns on" the listener immediately once componentDidMount happens.

In the componentDidMount lifecycle method, we are attaching a listener to using **.listen**. That's invoked. Just for convenience, we are assigning the result of the function to this.unsubscribe.

If you look at lines 60-68 of this gist (https://gist.github.com/spoike/ba561727a3f133b942dc#file-reflux-js-L60-L68) think of .listen returning a function that that removes the event listener.

In componentWillUnmount, we invoke this.unsubscribe which removes the listener. You can think of .listen as returning a function that removes the 'listener' and when the componentWillUnmount lifecycle happens we invoke that function and kill the listener.

*Tl;dr: Imagine .listen attaches a listener AND returns a function that turns off the listener-- when you first invoke it the listener on and when you invoke the function that gets returned it turns off the listener*